# Как сделать высоту до низа

Tags: html, css, height

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: -265px;
    width:265px;
    background: #2db8d7;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 265px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 265px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
}

.block {height:1200px;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      </div>
      
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="block">
            test
            
            
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы высота у `#sidebar-wrapper` растягивалась до низа страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: -265px;
    width:265px;
    background: #2db8d7;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 265px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 265px;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
}

.block {height:1200px;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      </div>
      
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="block">
            test
            
            
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Добавить:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```